# Multiprocessing Starmap returns list instead of dictionary

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm running a function that is meant to return a dictionary variable through starmaps with multiple inputs. However, when I print the final output produced from multiprocessing I get a list type variable instead. Why does this happen, and is there a workaround? Thanks.

Example:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def return_dict(keys, values):
    dict =dict(zip(keys, values))
    print(type(dict))
    return dict

with Pool(3) as p:
    output = p.starmap(return_dict, [(['name', 'age', 'nationality'], ['Bob', 17, 'Korean']),
                                     (['price', 'fruit', 'drink'], [20, 'banana', 'juice']),
                                     (['color1', 'color2', 'color3'], ['red', 'blue', 'green']))
print(type(output))
```

Output:

```
<class 'dict'>
<class 'dict'>
<class 'dict'>
<class 'list'>
```

Comment: can you describe more about the expected output?

Comment: hoping for it to be a dictionary variable instead of a list variable

Comment: Print `output` itself - it's likely a list of these dictionaries

Comment: That was the problem, thank you! Just have to loop through the list to get the dictionaries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the desired result the way below. Also my advise is to do such easy operations in one process and not to use `Pool`

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool


def return_dict(keys, values):
    # use dictionary comprehension to create dictionary
    _dict = {keys[i]: values[i] for i in range(len(keys))}
    print(type(_dict))
    return _dict


if __name__ == '__main__':

    data = [
        (
            ['name', 'age', 'nationality'],
            ['Bob', 17, 'Korean'],
        ),
        (
            ['price', 'fruit', 'drink'],
            [20, 'banana', 'juice'],
        ),
        (
            ['color1', 'color2', 'color3'],
            ['red', 'blue', 'green'],
        )
    ]

    with Pool(3) as p:
        output = p.starmap(return_dict, data)

    for j in output:
        print(j)
```

Comment: Thanks, this was just a simplified example